# Tkinter scrollbar missing after treeview update

Tags: python, tkinter

I have issue dealing with scrollbar in tkinter.

I enclosed `Treeview` and `Scrollbar`  widgets inside a frame for easier grouping. The problem is that when I update the `Treeview` to display a table with many columns, the scroll bar suddenly disappears (scroll bar retains only when at most 3 columns are displayed).

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.minsize(800, 700)
window.geometry("800x700")
...
middle = tk.Frame(window)
middle.pack(fill='x', side='top')
#red background for visualizing only
middle.configure(background='red')

displayTable = ttk.Treeview(middle, show='headings', selectmode="browse")
displayTable.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

#style for the table
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("clam")
style.map("Treeview")
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Consolas", 12))
style.configure("Treeview", rowheight=30)

tabScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(middle, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=displayTable.yview)
displayTable.configure(yscrollcommand=tabScroll.set)
tabScroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y')
```

I want that the scroll bar widget will not disappear whenever I display tables with cols > 3. Any idea where is the issue? I dont want to use `grid()` since the main window is resizable.

Table with 2 columns:

[image]

Table with 6 columns:

[image]

*Note: data in table are fictitious*

> EDIT: as requested, below are the two variants for the working example:
>
> **Table with 2 rows:**
>
> ```
> import tkinter as tk
> from tkinter import ttk
>
> window = tk.Tk()
> window.minsize(800, 700)
> window.geometry("800x700")
>
> middle = tk.Frame(window)
> middle.pack(fill='x', side='top')
> #red background for visualizing only
> middle.configure(background='red')
>
> displayTable = ttk.Treeview(middle, show='headings', selectmode="browse")
> displayTable.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
>
> #headings
> columns = ("id", "name")
> displayTable['column'] = columns
> displayTable.heading("# 1",text="id")
> displayTable.heading("# 2",text="name")
>
> #rows
> for n in range(1, 100):
>     displayTable.insert('', tk.END, values=(n, f"Row entry{n}"))
>
> #style for the table
> style = ttk.Style()
> style.theme_use("clam")
> style.map("Treeview")
> style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Consolas", 12))
> style.configure("Treeview", rowheight=30)
>
> tabScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(middle, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=displayTable.yview)
> displayTable.configure(yscrollcommand=tabScroll.set)
> tabScroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y')
>
> window.mainloop()
> ```
>
> **Table with 4 rows:**
>
> ```
> import tkinter as tk
> from tkinter import ttk
>
> window = tk.Tk()
> window.minsize(800, 700)
> window.geometry("800x700")
>
> middle = tk.Frame(window)
> middle.pack(fill='x', side='top')
> #red background for visualizing only
> middle.configure(background='red')
>
> displayTable = ttk.Treeview(middle, show='headings', selectmode="browse")
> displayTable.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
>
> #headings
> columns = ("id", "name", "job", "number")
> displayTable['column'] = columns
> displayTable.heading("# 1",text="id")
> displayTable.heading("# 2",text="name")
> displayTable.heading("# 3",text="job")
> displayTable.heading("# 4",text="number")
>
> #rows
> for n in range(1, 100):
>     displayTable.insert('', tk.END, values=(n, f"Row entry{n}", f"Job{n}", f"09-{n}"))
>
> #style for the table
> style = ttk.Style()
> style.theme_use("clam")
> style.map("Treeview")
> style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Consolas", 12))
> style.configure("Treeview", rowheight=30)
>
> tabScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(middle, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=displayTable.yview)
> displayTable.configure(yscrollcommand=tabScroll.set)
> tabScroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y')
>
> window.mainloop()
> ```
>
> My goal is that to not suppress the scrollbar when the table displays more than 3 columns (in that specific window dimensions). Hope this helps.

Comment: you could create minimal working code with example columns in treeview - it would be simpler to test it.

Comment: @furas I updated my post to show the issue

Comment: In the second picture there is no space for the scrollbar (no more red area), so to see it probably a horizontal scrollbar is needed to make it visible? This rises the question is scrolling still possible with more than 3 columns (arrow keys with mouse pointer over the window)?

Comment: from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561030/vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars-on-tkinter-widget#9566381 : "A quick fix is to pack the vertical scrollbar first, then the horizontal, and then the canvas. Your "major" widget should always be one of the last things you pack/grid. ". I suppose this will solve the problem. Does it?

Comment: @Claudio I tried your suggestion and thanks it actually worked. Solved the issue by packing the scrollbar first then the table.