# scroll bar disappears [Tkinter, treeview]

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scroll, treeview

I have a problem: when there are a large number of columns in the table, they go beyond the window field along with the scroll

Tell me what's wrong, please

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x300')

    def run(self):
        self.interface()
        self.content()

    def interface(self):

        frame = Frame()
        frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=1)
                
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame)
        self.tree.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)

        sc_y = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        sc_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
          
        self.tree["yscrollcommand"]=sc_y.set

    def content(self):
        people = [("Tom", 38, "tom@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Tom", 38, "tom@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com")]

        columns = ("name", "age", "email", "name1", "age1", "email1")

        self.tree.config(columns=columns, show="headings")

        self.tree.heading("name", text="Имя")
        self.tree.heading("age", text="Возраст")
        self.tree.heading("email", text="Email")
        self.tree.heading("name1", text="Имя")
        self.tree.heading("age1", text="Возраст")
        self.tree.heading("email1", text="Email")

        for i in columns:
            self.tree.column(i, stretch=NO)

        for person in people:
            self.tree.insert("", END, values=person)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = Main()
    A.run()
```

I have already reviewed all the monuals, tutirials. No one writes about this problem.

[Added gif file to understand the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4B7W.gif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the small modifications I made. It was a problem of how the `Scrollbar` was defined and where. The changes are in the function `interface()`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x300')

    def run(self):
        self.interface()
        self.content()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def interface(self):

        
        frame = Frame()
        frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=1)

        sc_y = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
        sc_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
                
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, yscrollcommand=sc_y.set)
        self.tree.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)

        sc_y.config(command=self.tree.yview)

        

    def content(self):
        people = [("Tom", 38, "tom@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Bob", 42, "bob@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Sam", 28, "sam@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com"),
                  ("Tom", 38, "tom@email.com", "Tom", 38, "tom@email.com")]

        columns = ("name", "age", "email", "name1", "age1", "email1")

        self.tree.config(columns=columns, show="headings")

        self.tree.heading("name", text="Имя")
        self.tree.heading("age", text="Возраст")
        self.tree.heading("email", text="Email")
        self.tree.heading("name1", text="Имя")
        self.tree.heading("age1", text="Возраст")
        self.tree.heading("email1", text="Email")

        for i in columns:
            self.tree.column(i, stretch=NO)

        for person in people:
            self.tree.insert("", END, values=person)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = Main()
    A.run()
```

Here I show you the Output GIF:

[image]

The change has been the order of the scrollbar declaration, so that the program execution flow shows the scrollbar in the correct position.

```
        # First place
        sc_y = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
        sc_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # Second place                    
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, yscrollcommand=sc_y.set)
        self.tree.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)
```

The key is to `pack()` in this order, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9566381/1688501) answer:

1. Vertical scrollbar.
2. Horizontal scrollbar (if there was one).
3. Treeview.

Comment: Please highlight and add a brief explanation to your changes. Future visitors will thank you for.